# How can I delete a dom instance in Angularjs view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm making a simple mailer interface and I have a setup that looks like ...

```
                <tbody ng-controller="sentboxCtrl">
                    <tr ng-repeat="message in sent">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{| message.id |}"></td>        
                        <td><a href="#" value="{| message.id |}" class="view-message-link">{| message['subject'] |}</a></td>
                        <td>

                            <img class="attachement" value="{| message.id |}" ng-if="message.attachment" src="{| attachmentIcon |}" width="20" height="20" alt=""></td>
                        <td>{| message.name |}</td>        
                        <td>{| message.created |}</td>
                        <td><a href="#" value="{| message.id |}" class="flagMessage"><img value="{| message.id |}" src="{| flagIcon |}" width="20" height="20" alt=""></a></td>
                        <td><a href="#" value="{| message.id |}" class="deleteMessage" ng-click="delete({| message |})"><img value="{| message.id |}" src="{| deleteIcon |}" width="20" height="20" alt=""></a></td>
                    </tr>   
                 </tbody>
```

My code that configures my controller is as follows:

```
var mailApp = angular.module('mailApp',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{|');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('|}');
    }
);

var sentboxCtrl = function ($scope){

    $scope.sent = initiallySent;
    $scope.deleteIcon = deleteIconSource;
    $scope.flagIcon = flagIconSource;
    $scope.attachmentIcon = attachmentIconSource;

    $scope.delete = function(element)
    {
        delete element;
    }

};

mailApp.controller('sentboxCtrl',sentboxCtrl);
```

Now since I have an ng-repeat attribute that generates my dom for the messaging platform, I would like to tie in the event ng-click to trigger a delete for that row. An example would be:

```
<td><a href="#" ng-click="delete(this)" value="{| message.id |}" class="deleteMessage" ng-click="delete({| message |})"><img value="{| message.id |}" src="{| deleteIcon |}" width="20" height="20" alt=""></a></td>
```

Is it possible to do this without writting too much boiler plate code?

Thanks

Comment: If the row is generated from the ng-repeat, you should simply delete the element from $scope.sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$scope.delete = function(i) {
   $scope.sent.splice(i, 1);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" value="{| message.id |}" class="deleteMessage" ng-click="delete($index)"><img value="{| message.id |}" src="{| deleteIcon |}" width="20" height="20" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer on my own to, but this is exactly what I did anyway.

Comment: That is what's important.